# Scrapy get text outside the selector

Tags: python, scrapy

```
<div style="display:none">o</div> <br>
Your Text Str1<br>Your Text Str2<br>Your Text Str3
```

i want to get  All text after br tag in list

```
response.xpath('//div[@style = "display:none"]').extract()
```

return this string

```
    <div style="display:none">o</div>
```

using sibling

```
 response.xpath('//div[@style = "display:none"]/following-sibling').extract()
```

return []

Comment: `//div[@style = "display:none"]/../text()`?

Comment: @Gallaecio your solution works for me. Thanks!